# mod_rewrite always uses index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rebuilding one of my websites (redesign + pdo instead of regular mysql).
So far so good, everything works out, except from 1 RewriteRule in .htaccess.

All of my url-rewrites are going fine with this kind of rule:

```
RewriteRule pages/(.*)/ index.php?type=page&page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule pages/(.*) index.php?type=page&page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

(note: making use of index.php)

For my shopping cart, I want to use a clean, separate page, with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/shopping-cart-overview/$ /pages/shoppingcart/overview.php
RewriteRule ^shop/shopping-cart-overview$ /pages/shoppingcart/overview.php
```

Problem: instead of using the file "/pages/shoppingcart/overview.php", it still uses index.php as in the other rules.

I uploaded full htaccess in txt, so you can read it yourself:
[www.mymobisite.be/htaccess.txt](http://www.mymobisite.be/htaccess.txt)

Thank you in advance for your time, help and advice!

Tom V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order of the rules. The `shop/shopping-cart` comes before the `pages` rule. 
The first rule rewrites `shop/shopping-cart-overview/` to `/pages/shoppingcart/overview.php`, which in turn is rewritten to `index.php?type=page&page=shoppingcart/overview.php`.

You should either reorder your rewrite rules or use the `[L]` modifier (L=last).

```
RewriteRule ^shop/shopping-cart-overview/$ /pages/shoppingcart/overview.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^shop/shopping-cart-overview$ /pages/shoppingcart/overview.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I tried putting this rule on the last line / tried to add the L modifier, but none of both seems to work...

Comment: I renamed the /pages/ so it doesn't overwrite as you say, now it works :) Thank you for the answer @lorenz